# Guile Scheme - How to pass C struct value back to Guile for scripting

Tags: c, scripting, scheme, guile

I'm writing a program/game where I use Guile for scripting on top of a C program.
For example I have a command struct type(which is also used for move_to) in C and corresponding
`move_to` wrapper function to to create move_to commands in Guile. In the UI an input line can be entered
and is then executed in Guile.

For `move_to` it look like this in C:
Some entity id is passed here as a SCM value, same for the new
the position and SCM value is passed for x and the same for y.

```c
    static SCM move_to(SCM scm_id, SCM x, SCM y) {

        unsigned int id = scm_to_int(scm_id);
        float new_x = scm_to_double(x);
        float new_y = scm_to_double(y);

        // Search for entity 
       int index = -1;
       for (int i = 0; i < gs.entities.size(); i++) {

           if (get_id(&(gs.entities[i])) == id) { index = i; break; }
       }

      command c = {new_x,new_y,MOVETO,0};

      // Add move command to entity if one was found
      if (index != -1) { printf("found index\n");add_command(&(gs.entities[index]), c); }

      return SCM_UNSPECIFIED;
    }
```

In this code the entity is searched in some entity list and if it exist, we
create a new `move_to_command` and add it to the command list of the entity.

In the UI then e.g. `(move_to 0 100 100)` can be entered and is then executed.

It's straightforward when creating a C function and wrapper when the function just returns
an integer or nothing at all. But I'm not sure how to implement a function which returns a (C-/Guile-) struct value
to Guile.

Let's say we have this struct type in C:

```
typedef struct {
  unsigned int id;
  event_type type;
  unsigned int entity_id;
  unsigned int by_entity;
} event;
```

How would I go to create a Guile struct value from this C struct which is returned when
when for example some Guile function - like `'get-next-event'`(which I have to write) is called. It would now also
be OK if I had to copy the value from the C struct to a new Guile struct over.

Saw that there is the function `scm_make_struct(SCM vtable, SCM tail_size, SCM init_list)`,
but I am not sure how to create a vtable value which to pass here as a first argument.

I think older guile versions there was `scm_make_vtable_vtable`.
Also I tried the C-function `scm_struct_vtable` from the current version.

ADDENDUM:

- found a function to create a vtable in the file struct.h, which is not documented: `SCM_API SCM scm_make_vtable (SCM fields, SCM printer);`

Source Code Example:

```
#include "libguile.h"

static SCM give_me_100(void) {

  return scm_from_int(100);
}

static SCM give_me_a_struct(void) {

  SCM fields = scm_from_locale_string("pwpw");
  SCM vtable = scm_make_vtable(fields,0);

  SCM mystruct = scm_c_make_struct(vtable,0, 10, 20,  SCM_UNDEFINED);                                                                                             //

  return mystruct;

}

static void inner_main(void *closure, int argc, char **argv) {

    /* preparation - make C functions callable from Guile */
    scm_c_define_gsubr("give-me-100", 0, 0, 0, &give_me_100);
    scm_c_define_gsubr("give-me-a-struct", 0, 0, 0, &give_me_a_struct);

    scm_shell(argc, argv);
    /* after exit */
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    scm_boot_guile(argc, argv, inner_main, 0);
    return 0; /* never reached, see inner_main */
}
```

Which can be compiled with this line for example:
gcc -o main -I/usr/include/guile/3.0 -lguile-3.0 main.c

Example output:

```
GNU Guile 3.0.8
Copyright (C) 1995-2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Guile comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details type `,show w'.
This program is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; type `,show c' for details.

Enter `,help' for help.
scheme@(guile-user)> (give-me-100)
$1 = 100
scheme@(guile-user)> (give-me-a-struct)
$2 = zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./main
```

Thank you for any help and suggestions,
Rael

Comment: Have you read https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Defining-New-Foreign-Object-Types.html ?

Comment: (If you go that foreign object route, you have to also define accessor functions for all the fields yourself)

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Foreign-Function-Interface.html is another option if you don't need to have changes made to the struct be visible in C. Write a scheme function that, given a pointer to one of your structs, unpacks the fields and creates a guile record with the same data.

Comment: @Shawn -Thank you - tried the example with the image type struct before, but it didn't work for me. I will again look into the documentation, and check the links and try again. I'm hoping that there is some simple solution.

Comment: @Shawn Thank you, with the documentation link you provided and example from github I was able to implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use and export C structs to Guile, one could do it like this -
the example code is from here: https://github.com/agentlans/guile-foreign-example/blob/master/bessel.c

```
#include <math.h>
#include <libguile.h>

// Returns value of j0 Bessel function. This will be called from Guile Scheme.
SCM
j0_wrapper (SCM x)
{
    return scm_from_double (j0 (scm_to_double (x)));
}

// A C struct that can hold any Guile Scheme object
struct foo
{
    SCM x;
};

// Represents the foo type in Scheme
static SCM foo_type;

// Declarations needed for foo structs to be usable in Scheme
void init_foo_type()
{
    SCM name = scm_from_utf8_symbol("foo");
    SCM slots = scm_list_1(scm_from_utf8_symbol("x"));
    foo_type = scm_make_foreign_object_type(name, slots, NULL); // NULL finalizer
}

// Creates a new foo struct containing the given Scheme object
SCM make_foo(SCM obj)
{
    struct foo *foo_obj = scm_gc_malloc(sizeof(struct foo), "foo");
    foo_obj->x = obj;
    return scm_make_foreign_object_1(foo_type, foo_obj);
}

// Returns the Scheme object inside the foo struct
SCM get_foo(SCM foo_obj)
{
    scm_assert_foreign_object_type(foo_type, foo_obj);
    return ((struct foo *) scm_foreign_object_ref(foo_obj, 0))->x;
}

// Initializes the functions exposed in this Guile extension
void
init_bessel ()
{
    scm_c_define_gsubr ("j0", 1, 0, 0, j0_wrapper);

    init_foo_type();
    scm_c_define_gsubr("make-foo", 1, 0, 0, make_foo);
    scm_c_define_gsubr("get-foo", 1, 0, 0, get_foo);
}
```